# I get an error message when I attempt to extend ImageView in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

In Android Studio I am attempting to extend the ImageView widget, but am getting the error message "there is no default constructor available in 'android.widget.ImageView'" .  How can I resolve this error?

My code is as follows:

package com.example.trendpoints;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CouponImageView extends ImageView {

```
public CouponImageView(Context c) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you just need to add `super(c);`. The compiler is telling that there is no available default constructor available. The default constructor is the one without parameters, that without `super(c)`, you are trying to call in an implicit way

```
public CouponImageView(Context c) {
       super(c);
}
```